# Objective-C: const char* string getting corrupted: what's going on?

Tags: objective-c, c, string

I'm encountering a weird issue where a const char string is getting corrupted after it's been initialised.

In my .m file I have a pointer declared like so:

```
const char *s;

@implementation MyClass
...
@end
```

It's initialised in `-init`, and looks fine at that point:

```
-init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        s = [@"obfuscatedString" deobfuscatedCString];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Later, when I come to read it, the address of the pointer is unchanged, but the value's been overwritten.

I've stripped it down to the bare essentials, and can confirm that the string is not otherwise used, and there doesn't appear to be anything else that might corrupt it.

So, what's going on? Is there some fundamental bit of objective-c I'm not aware of?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post your `-init` method?

Comment: I'm not a profy in objective-C, but in general, the corruption may be caused by any incorrect memory operation, like accessing an array by out-of-bounds index, using of freed memory block, and so on. Try using debugger to detect the exact place where the memory is changed. Also you can use some tool to catch heap errors (like Rational Purify...)

Comment: You don't set `S` in `init`. Or is the global variable actually called `SBSERVPATH`?

Comment: @mipadi Have corrected the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `deobfuscatedCString` use autorelease objects when deobfuscating? maybe the returned address points to memory that gets freed when one of them gets dealloced.

If that is the case and you still want `s` to be a `char *`, try:

```
s = strdup([@"obfuscatedString" deobfuscatedCString]);
```

Comment: Yes! Turns out it was being autoreleased. Didn't expect -cStringUsingEncoding to manage a C pointer was it would Cocoa objects. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't give us much information, you know :)

I think it's bad coding style in any case, so my advice would be the following: make S an instance variable. Really.

Comment: S needs to be a class variable as it's used like a string constant, but it needs to be created at run-time as doing that every time it's used would be needlessly expensive.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly because the memory for your C string gets released at some point. If you absolutely must have that global (and from the fact that you initialize it from your constructor it sounds like this may not be entirely right), make it `NSString *`. It will hold on to its value until it is released explicitly. Use `cStringUsingEncoding` whenever a conversion to `char*` is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any code which could make us understand what is going on so we won't be able to help you here. Please give more details.

But anyway, even if you did write only 3 lines of code in your question, this is already horrible coding style:

- You use const char* whereas NSString is probably more appropriate to work with other Cocoa objects
- You use a global variable, which is very bad coding style and will probably lead you to problems (like concurrent access problems and much more). Use an instance variable instead. Really.
- Your variable name is only one character long, which is a really bad habit and does not help to make the code easily understandable. a name like "S" is far from descriptive
- You name your variable starting with an uppercase, whereas names starting with uppercase should be reserved for classes names, and instance variables should stard with lowercase. If this is a constant, it may be written in all-uppercase (and not title-case), but as your variable name is only 1-letter-long anyway...

In short, make sure you read the programming guides and use the good habits right now (like avoiding global constants of type `char*` if not strictly necessary) or it will lead you to errors (like memory corruption) hard to debug later. And give use more code if you want us to help on your original problem.

Comment: Apologies for not posting more information: this is for work and I can't post the real code. This is just pseudo-code. As for using Cocoa objects - yes, that would work, but it'd require an additional step every time I wanted to use the string in a C function. This *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something else is mucking with the pointer or its contents at some point. I'd wrap the constant in a class method, and make sure to only modify it from within that. Something like this:

```
+ (const char *)globalCString
{
    static const char *s = NULL;
    if (!s) s = [@"obfuscatedString" deobfuscatedCString];
    return s;
}
```